# Plotting the distinct combination of rows in R

Tags: r, plot, unique, frequency-distribution

I have a data frame like this:

```
LR_ID               Proc_ID
   1                   2
   1                  10
   1                  10
   1                   2
   2                  10
   3                  10
   4                   3
   5                   3
   5                  10
```

The idea is to get frequency distinct LR_IDs associated with a Proc_ID.

I have counted the frequency of Proc_ID and LR_ID like this:

```
 library(plyr)
 count_0 <- count(my_df)
```

which has given me a result like this:

```
 LR_ID     Proc_ID      Freq
   1          0        1154
   1          1         980
   1          2        1256
```

and so on.. I have 20 process IDs (0 to 19) and around 800 LR_IDs so all the combinations.
I want to plot this where one axis will be the process ids (0 to 19, in this case) and showing the frequency of distinct LR_IDs associated with one process id.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)
my_df %>%
  count(LR_ID, Proc_ID) %>%
  ggplot(aes(LR_ID, Proc_ID, fill = n, label = n)) +
  geom_tile(alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_text() +
  scale_x_continuous(minor_breaks = NULL) +
  scale_y_continuous(minor_breaks = NULL, breaks = 1:800) +  
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Sample data

```
my_df <- tibble::tribble(
    ~LR_ID, ~Proc_ID,
        1L,       2L,
        1L,      10L,
        1L,      10L,
        1L,       2L,
        2L,      10L,
        3L,      10L,
        4L,       3L,
        5L,       3L,
        5L,      10L
    )
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. Your plot looks what I want but when I am trying to do I am getting this error:        Error in count(., LR_ID, Proc_ID) : object 'LR_ID' not found                                               my colnames are LR_ID and Proc_ID yet I don't know why I am getting the error.  This is the output of dput(head(my_df)) :    structure(list(LR_ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Proc_ID = c(5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L)), row.names = c(1L, 5L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 13L
), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Try loading the sample data I added at the bottom of my answer, then running the code. If it runs, I suggest double checking your column names. (e.g. you had `ProcID` in your original question but `Proc_ID` in your comment above...)

Comment: I tried running with the sample data that you provided. It is still showing the same error.  :(

Comment: And you have loaded dplyr in this session and you are running the whole chain? The error makes it sound like the `count` line is running without the `my_df %>%` line preceding it, since R is looking for an object called `LR_ID` when the line before it should have fed the tibble called `my_df` into `count`. (equivalent to starting with `count(my_df, LR_ID, Proc_ID) %>%`). That should work, provided that `my_df` is loaded, and `dplyr` is loaded so that you have the `%>%` operator.

Comment: @JonSmith count expects a data.frame/tibble. According to ?dplyr::count. Is that why I am getting the error?

Comment: It is working now. I had to restart the whole session and start from scratch. Maybe some previously loaded libraries were having conflicts. Thank you again @JonSmith.